# How do I select only the first option matching a value using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I’m using JQuery 1.8.   I want to select an option in my select menu by value so I use this statement

```
$('.countryField').find('option[value="233"]')
```

however, the problem with the above is if there are multiple options with the same value, all are selected.  How do I adjust the above statement so that only one option is selected?  Feel free to message me and lecture about how there should not be select menu with multiple options with the same values.

**Edit:** Here is the console output in response to one of the suggestions given

```
> $('.countryField').find('option').prop('selected', false)
jQuery.fn.init[255]
> $('.countryField').find('option[value="233"]:first').prop('selected', true)
[<option value=​"233" selected=​"selected">​United States​</option>​]
> $('.countryField').find('option[selected="selected"]')
[<option value=​"233" selected=​"selected">​United States​</option>​, <option selected=​"selected" value=​"233">​United States​</option>​]
```

Comment: In response to your edit - You're setting the `selected` **property**, then selecting elements with a `selected` **attribute**. Updating the value of a property of an object does not change its html element attributes. The answers to set the property are correct, but you're not selecting properly - https://jsfiddle.net/h9neus61/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector here which selects the first matched DOM element.

```
$('.countryField').find('option[value="233"]:first')
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I included the console ouptut in my edit.  After applying your suggestion, there are still two options selected.

Comment: Do you have multiple `countryField` select elements in the page?

Comment: Check once how many `countryField` select elements you have on the page like `$('.countryField').length`. Then you can select on one select list like `$('.countryField:first').length`, then check `$('.countryField:first').find('option[value="233"]:first').length` & `$('.countryField:first').find('option[selected="selected"]').length`

Comment: Thanks for your continued help on this.  Indeed, I only have one element on the page as running "$('.countryField').length" produces "1".

Comment: @Mike Could you please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0):

:eq(0) will used to choose first option having value "233" and it will be get selected.

```
$('.countryField [value="233"]:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: As with palash's suggestion, this also doesn't work.  The edit in my question lists the output.  If you replace "$('.countryField').find('option[value="233"]:first')" with your suggestion, the output is still two selected options.

Answer (score 0):

**this can also be done with pure Javascript**

```
document.querySelector(' .countryField option').setAttribute('selected','selected')
```

Comment: All this does is output hte first option in the list.  It doesan't select or de-select anything.